# Why does high-memory not exist for 64-bit cpu?

Tags: linux, cpu-architecture, virtual-memory

While I am trying to understand the high memory problem for 32-bit cpu and Linux, why is there no [high-memory problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_memory) for 64-bit cpu?

In particular, how is the division of virtual memory into kernel space and user space changed, so that the requirement of high memory doesn't exist for 64-bit cpu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 32-bit  system can only address 4GB of memory.  In Linux this is divided into 3GB of user space and 1GB of kernel space. This 1GB is sometimes not enough so the kernel might need to map and unmap areas of memory which incurs a fairly significant performance penalty.  The kernel space is the "high" 1GB hence the name "high memory problem".

A 64-bit system can address a **huge** amount of memory - 16 EB -so this issue does not occur there.

Comment: Why does the same problem for 32-bit not also happens to 64-bit? In 64-bit system, the kernel space is also limited, when the kernel tries to map the physical memory into the kernel space.

Comment: In Linux, the kernel space grows from the top 1/4 of 2^32 to the top 1/2 of 2^64 -- which will be plenty for this universe.

Answer (score 2):

With 32-bit addresses, you can only address 2^32 bytes of memory (4GB). So if you have more that, you need to address it some special way. With 64-bit addresses, you can address 2^64 bytes of memory without special effort, and that number is way bigger than all the memory that exists on the planet.

Comment: Damn you got there first!

Comment: Thanks. But in my post, the high memory problem for 32-bit is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_memory. It puts a 896 MB limit on low memory.

Comment: That doesn't discuss any kind of problem. So I'm still not sure what you mean by "high memory problem". But I think it's the same answer -- with only 4GB, whatever you map for the kernel takes away from what you can map for user space.

Comment: From the Wikipedia article the "problem" is that there is insufficient virtual address (VA) space to fully map the physical address space when the physical address (PA) size is larger than the portion of the total VA space allocated in the OS section devoted to that purpose (Wikipedia is somewhat misleading in that 2GiB/2GiB [sign-bit-based] division was initially common; 3GiB/1GiB was an adaptation to support larger application space.). With 47 bits of VA space for the OS (in x86-64), even with only half used for the mapping, 64 TiB of PA space is available.

Answer (score 2):

That number of bits refers to the word size of the processor. Among other things, the word size is the size of a memory address on your machine. The size of the memory address affects how many bytes can be referenced uniquely. So doing some simple math we find that on a 32 bit system at most 2^32 = 4294967296 memory addresses exist, meaning you have a mathematical limitation to about 4GB of RAM.

However on a 64 bit system you have 2^64 = 1.8446744e+19 memory address available. This means that your computer can theoretically reference almost 20 exabytes of RAM, which is more RAM than anyone has ever needed in the history of computing.

Comment: Thanks. But in my post, the high memory problem for 32-bit is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_memory. It puts a 896 MB limit on low memory.

Comment: @Tim That article is referring to a limitation on Kernel space memory, which is the minority of memory in a system. It does not refer to memory in general.