# how to copy from one physical page to another in kernel

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel

I have a list of 16, 4K physical pages (represented by struct page) which I want to gather into one contiguous huge page of 64KB. This is of course to be done in kernel. 
Right now I'm doing this as follows (the bellow might have errors, it's just for the idea):

```
struct page *huge_page = alloc_pages(gfp_flags, get_order(16*PAGE_SIZE));
char *gather_buff = (char *)kmap(huge_page); 
for (i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
     char* tmp_addr = (char *)kmap(small_pages_arr[i]);
     memcpy(gather_buff + i*PAGE_SIZE, tmp_addr, PAGE_SIZE);
     kunmap(small_pages_arr[i]);
}
kunmap(huge_page);
```

I'm afraid that the kmap/kunmap is very inefficient performance wise and was wondering if there is another way of doing this?
(Looked at copy_on_write for reference but must admit that got lost there)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe kmap/kunmap amount to a simple pointer arithmetic operation on x86_64 systems, so it shouldn't affect performance significantly.

There are some more details about high memory in 64-bit systems in this question: [Why does high-memory not exist for 64-bit cpu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35620385/why-does-high-memory-not-exist-for-64-bit-cpu)

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure I understand how can it be just pointer arithmetic. Shouldn't the kmap/unmap involve page table updates? Locate free PTE, update the mapping, update the page as mapped etc....

Comment: Because there is no high mem area in 64-bit systems, all of the physical pages are mapped to the kernel page tables in advance.